# Why is xorg-edgers PPA not updated with nvidia-current?

Tags: nvidia

Nvidia 313.18 was released a couple of weeks ago and I was not notified of a possible upgrade. I have the *xorg-edgers ppa* installed but when I tried installing nvidia-current it said i was up to date with *313.09* even thought build *313.18* was in the repository.
I was finally able to install 313.18 by installin nvidia-313.
I just wanted to know why this happened and if I need to this in the future to receive updates.

Comment: how did you install `nvidia-current` from xorg-edgers ppa? i cant find `nvidia-current` on their repository, they just have `nvidia-310` and `nvidia-313`

Answer (score 0):

1- the question is pin-priority
2- to overcome this we have to

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/preferences
```

in the file that opens add the following rule

```
Package: *
Pin: origin ppa.launchpad.net
Pin-Priority: 700
```

May fix it has some issues with a different ppa.