# trouble upgrading to kernel 3.7.6 from 3.7.5

Tags: kernel

Is kernel 3.7.6 compatible with nvidia driver 313.18. I tried installing it through the upubuntu guide but I was getting an error. I tried using their fix but it said the directories were not found. Any suggestions

This is what i get

```
Unpacking replacement linux-headers-3.7.6-030706-generic ...
Preparing to replace linux-headers-3.7.6-030706 3.7.6-030706.201302040006 (using linux-headers-3.7.6-030706_3.7.6-030706.201302040006_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement linux-headers-3.7.6-030706 ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-3.7.6-030706-generic.
Unpacking linux-image-3.7.6-030706-generic (from linux-image-3.7.6-030706-generic_3.7.6-030706.201302040006_amd64.deb) ...
Done.
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-extra-3.7.6-030706-generic.
Unpacking linux-image-extra-3.7.6-030706-generic (from linux-image-extra-3.7.6-030706-generic_3.7.6-030706.201302040006_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.7.6-030706 (3.7.6-030706.201302040006) ...
Setting up linux-image-3.7.6-030706-generic (3.7.6-030706.201302040006) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.7.6-030706-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.6-030706-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.7.6-030706-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.7.6-030706-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-313/313.18/build/make.log for more information.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.7.6-030706-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.6-030706-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.7.6-030706-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.7.6-030706-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.6-030706-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.7.6-030706-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.6-030706-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.7.6-030706-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.6-030706-generic
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.6-030706-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7.6-030706-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.5-030705-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7.5-030705-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.4-030704-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7.4-030704-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.3-030703-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7.3-030703-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.2-030702-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7.2-030702-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.1-030701-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7.1-030701-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.0-030700-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7.0-030700-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.0-7-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7.0-7-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.0-4-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7.0-4-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.10-030610-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.6.10-030610-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.9-030609-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.6.9-030609-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-19-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-19-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
Setting up linux-image-extra-3.7.6-030706-generic (3.7.6-030706.201302040006) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.7.6-030706-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.6-030706-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.7.6-030706-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.7.6-030706-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-313/313.18/build/make.log for more information.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.7.6-030706-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.6-030706-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.7.6-030706-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.7.6-030706-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.6-030706-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.7.6-030706-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.6-030706-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.7.6-030706-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.6-030706-generic
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.6-030706-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7.6-030706-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.5-030705-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7.5-030705-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.4-030704-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7.4-030704-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.3-030703-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7.3-030703-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.2-030702-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7.2-030702-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.1-030701-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7.1-030701-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.0-030700-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7.0-030700-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.0-7-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7.0-7-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.0-4-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.7.0-4-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.10-030610-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.6.10-030610-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.6.9-030609-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.6.9-030609-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-19-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-19-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
Setting up linux-headers-3.7.6-030706-generic (3.7.6-030706.201302040006) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.7.6-030706-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.7.6-030706-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.7.6-030706-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.7.6-030706-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-313/313.18/build/make.log for more information.
```

Comment: Ok. #1: Going from 3.7.6 to 3.7.5 would be a *downgrade*. Do you mean the other way around? Give us the link to your fix. As stated often here, *tell us what you did*.

Comment: I'm running Nvidia `313.09` with `3.7.5-030705-generic`. Works splendidly *for me*. YMMV. You'll have to provide all steps you took and the *exact* error. Without specific information we're not able to answer your question.

Comment: How does this relate to your other question? [xorg-edgers PPA does not update with install nvidia-current](http://askubuntu.com/q/251381/88802)

Comment: HI, im trying to update to 3.7.6 from 3.7.5 that i have installed right now. I updated with the error i get. This only relates to my other question because its telling met to look at the nvidia-313.18  make.log...but the question about nvidia-currents is seperate from this

Comment: Yeah, well... what does the error log say? It's here, according to the error you posted: `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-313/313.18/build/make.log`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks cogitoergosum, that worked fine!

Editing `conftest.sh` in (`/usr/src/nvidia-current-310.19`) got me to install the kernel with nvidia 310.19.

I commented out lines 1703, 1704 and 1706, making it look like this:

```
PATCHLEVEL=$(grep "^PATCHLEVEL =" $MAKEFILE | cut -d " " -f 3)
            SUBLEVEL=$(grep "^SUBLEVEL =" $MAKEFILE | cut -d " " -f 3)
            # if [ -n "$PATCHLEVEL" -a $PATCHLEVEL -ge 6 \
            #         -a -n "$SUBLEVEL" -a $SUBLEVEL -le 5 ]; then
                SELECTED_MAKEFILE=Makefile.kbuild
                RET=0
            # fi
        fi
```

Then reinstalled the nvidia driver (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-current`) and made sure I saved the conftest.sh file after it was finished "`Unpacking replacement nvidia-current ...`".

And voila, kernel module building completed!

Comment: Thanks cogitoergosum for pointing out the problem and thanks irvine for showing what how you did it. I followed the steps and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest checking conftest.sh in /usr/src/nvidia-'version' directory. There is a small issue determining kernel version when PATCHLEVEL is 6 or greater (3.7.6 in this case). Comment out (#) if and fi lines and leave SELECTED_MAKEFILE and RET lines alone. Reinstall kernel headers and image debs, and nvidia.ko should build properly.

Update: If you are also running into compatibility issue between kernel 3.7.* and virtualbox, solution is to either 1) upgrade virtualbox to 4.2.6 -or- 2) patch memobj-r0drv-linux.c to replace VM_RESERVED macro with (VM_DONTEXPAND | VM_DONTDUMP). Good luck.